# Displaying a positive outstanding value with Woocommerce and deposit payments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on a Woocommerce website which requires deposit payments of £5 to be paid online the total value of the order (with the rest to be paid on collection). I have found some code that performs the correct calculations to force the checkout to £5

```
// Note: this will force Cart to $5

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'force_cart_to_5' );

function force_cart_to_5() {
    $total_minus_5 = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() - 5;
   WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Pay On Collection', - $total_minus_5 );
}
```

but it now lists the remaining balance as a minus figure. I would like to use it as a value to illustrate what they need to pay on collection:

[image][image]
I understand why this needs to be the case for the calculations, but is there a way to print a positive value every time this appears. I have managed to do this one one instance and just multiple the value by -1 when it prints out to the review order, but I want a catch all scenario I can just set once hwre the underlying value is negative to calculate the totals correct, but the printed value is positive.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `woocommerce_cart_totals_fee_html` filter, eg.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_fee_html', 'show_positive_fee_value', 10, 2 );
function show_positive_fee_value($cart_totals_fee_html, $fee) {
    if($fee->name === 'Pay On Collection') {
        $cart_totals_fee_html = wc_price( -( $fee->total) );
    }
    return $cart_totals_fee_html;
}
```

Comment: Hi markmoxx, Thanks for the answer, that seems to . work perfectly for the checkout page, I was kind of looking for something that would also change it on the order-received page, the order email, and in the clients dashboard as well.

Comment: Hi markmoxx,any idea on how to implement this accross the whole site rather than just the cart ( i.e, reports and emails)

Comment: It will involve some regex to edit the html output as I don't think it can be done via hooks.